Movie or TV series episode about a child dying from a parasite
I remember being four years old (in 1994) and watching a strange movie / TV series episode with my parents. There are was a boy, who gets sick from a parasite.
The part I remember the most is two adults (male and female; presumably his parents) going to the beach / coast and screaming "Come back! Come back!", which I really didn't get since the kid was still alive at the hospital; dying, but alive. I can't remember if he survives, though.
Also the bad guy (I'm pretty sure he was a criminal with a lot of power, like a gangster or a corrupt politician / CEO) from the movie died from the parasite (the parasite incidents were all his fault).
It seemed to be an American production, from the mid-late 80's.

White Dwarf, (1995).

In the year 3040, New York medical student Driscoll Rampart (Neal
  McDonough) is completing his internship on Rusta, a rural planet which
  due to it being tidally locked to its primary, is divided into
  contrasting halves of day and night with the halves separated by a
  wall. The two sides are involved in a civil war: The day side
  containing a Victorian-styled colony is at odds with the night
  containing a medieval kingdom.

The movie is available on Youtube, and the scene you describe is here.

That's the one! I thought I was 4 years old, but I was 6. I have no idea where I got the "gangster or corrupt person" thing. Maybe I mixed this movie with another one...?
I guess for sake of my mental health, my brain completely blocked the ocean of blood.
